# Can't get on my own web page

Tags: errors

When I try to go to my page this is the error I get. I can't even login it or anything.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare envira_standalone_get_slug() (previously declared in /homepages/15/d628531438/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/envira-standalone/envira-standalone.php:461) in /homepages/15/d628531438/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/envira-gallery/src/Functions/common.php on line 978

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two plugins installed that are trying to declare the same function `envira_standalone_get_slug()`. Both plugins are from the same creator, and this tells us that they aren't testing their plugins together.

The solution is to log in to your (S)FTP account, go to `/htdocs/wp-content/plugins`, and remove one of these directories: `envira-standalone/` or `envira-gallery/`.

Then you will be able to access your site again.

Please report this problem to the Envira team. I'm sure they want to fix that.

Comment: Please bare with me I am not savy in any of this, what is my FTP account?

Comment: @Melissa That is the access to the file system on the web server where your WordPress files are. You will find the access information and probably some guidelines in your web hosting account. Then use a program like [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) to open the FTP connection. When you aren't sure, ask your web hoster.